# angular HttpClient request returns 404. link is actif

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am trying to fetch data from a tomcat server to an angular application. 
On my tomcat server, I have a link that returns a json
and in my angular app I try to fetch the json with httpclient and httpheader.

When I copy the link from the angular code to my browser, the browser accepts it. Then a system message is shown in the terminal on the tomcat server.
However when I run the angular code, no terminal message is shown and in the console log of the angular app i see the error shown below.

Below is the java methods for generating a json response. The system out statements show json as expected.

```js
    public String toJSON(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    private void getAllUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("en deze request is GET-ALL-USERS ");
        String userJSON = this.toJSON(model.getPersons());
        System.out.println("en deze request is GET-ALL-USERS  = " + userJSON);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(userJSON);
    }
```

angular code to receive the json:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Gebruiker } from './gebruiker';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GebruikerService {
  private urlGetAllUsers = 'http://localhost:8081/Controller?action=angular&asyncAction=getAllUsers';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService) {

  }

  /** GET gebruikers from the server */
  getGebruikers (): Observable<Gebruiker[]> {
    const url = `${this.urlGetAllUsers}`;
    return this.http.get<Gebruiker[]>(url)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('fetched gebruikers')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getGebruikers', []))
      );
  }
  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

the error message i get in my console:

```
{body: {…}, url: "http://localhost:8081/Controller?action=angular&asyncAction=getAllUsers", headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}
body: {error: "Collection 'undefined' not found"}
headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: ƒ ()
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:8081/Controller?action=angular&asyncAction=getAllUsers"
__proto__: Object
```

I hope someone can help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you run the GET method from the browser, what does the browser passes in the request? Could you please screenshot the network tab of the get request that works? You could use Google Chrome's developer tools to capture the get request sent by the browser and you can paste it here as text or an image.

I am thinking, the browser is not passing 'Content-Type': 'application/json', but some other type (maybe it defaults to text). Also it is possible the tomcat server, which I assume is a Java EE based app, is not routing the request to the proper request handler.

Also could you provide your request mapping settings, which I assume you migh have in a web.xml config file for your servlet app (deployed to the Tomcat server).

Comment: hi sorry for the late response. someting cam up. i found what the problem was. i still had 
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
    )
in my app module. now i do have antoher error. but i guesse i will find it.

thanks

Comment: Great to hear that you were able to find a solution.